# PlaceAutocompleteAdapter - using background thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am quite new in android development and I am using this sample code from google, to get predictions of google places autocomplete:

https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-places/blob/master/PlaceCompleteAdapter/Application/src/main/java/com/example/google/playservices/placecomplete/PlaceAutocompleteAdapter.java

and in line 193 it says "This method MUST be called off the main UI thread"

How am I supposed to do this? I wanted to use AsyncTask for example, but I do not know how to do it in this context. Could somebody show me some example or give me some hint on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

here is an example async task where you can call the method from the background thread

```
 new AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResultType>() {
            @Override
            protected ResultType doInBackground(Void... params) {
                //call the places method here and return the results
                ResultType result = callingPlacesApi();
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ResultType searchResult) {
                //here i have my results returned from the background thread and can do anything with it
                MyViewxyz.updatewithplacesmethod(searchResult);
            }
        }.execute((Void) null);
```